# RF24 mesh with arduino 328p with 100 nodes

Tags: networking

I have explored [RF24Ethernet](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24Ethernet) library and I have tested same with 10 devices and Raspberry as my gateway. All seems to work fine.

My question is if I go with 100 sensor nodes with a single RPi, would it have a stable connectivity?

What is the data rate has to be selected in that case?

If someone have tested it with more than atleast 50 nodes please help me on this..

Comment: How do you implement RF24 mesh on the RasPi?

Comment: @Ingo Install library using https://github.com/TMRh20/tmrh20.github.io/blob/master/RF24Installer/RPi/install.sh, connect to pins and run the script..